# Mostrar algumas colunas no ListBox

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, listbox

Estou montando um sistema para minha empresa, onde quando eu clico em um botão ele está me trazendo todas as colunas da tabela, mas eu gostaria de especificar quais colunas eu quero exibir. Sendo que essas colunas não estão uma do lado da outra.

```
txtResult1.RowSource = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partindo do principio que você está utilizando ListBox, não será possível adicionar diretamente múltiplos intervalos na propriedade RowSource.

Você precisa definir seu intervalo antes e percorrê-lo adicionando os itens dentro do seu ListBox.

Veja um exemplo:

[image: Aqui temos meu intervalo em diferentes colunas]

Agora veja como ficou meu código:

```
Dim intervalo       As Range 'crio uma variável do tipo Range
Set intervalo = Sheets("NomeDaSuaAba").Range("F3:F6,J3:J7") ' Aqui informo quais são meus intervalos que eu quero adicionar ao meu range

For Each cell In intervalo ' percorro meu intervalo
    ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value 'adiciono o valor da celula dentro do meu listbox
Next
```

Meu resultado final:

[image: Imagem final]

Essa é apenas uma forma de fazer, mas existem várias maneiras, cada uma com suas vantagens e desvantagens.